# Could the 4-color theorem be proven by contracting snarks?

Tags: graph-theory, graph-colorings

Suppose someone came up with an algorithm that could take any snark and perform edge contraction to result in the Peterson graph.  If an inspection of the algorithm reveals that it works as claimed, would the algorithm be sufficient to prove the 4CT?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snark_(graph_theory)#Snark_theorem

Comment: Yes, but I was also wondering if the "proof by algorithm" approach (as I've worded my question) is a valid approach.  I suppose it's valid as long as the algorithm can be proven correct.

Comment: @prideout there are plenty of algorithmic proofs where the existence of some desired combinatorial object is demonstrated by giving an algorithm to find it. Some people like these proofs more than non-constructive proofs of existence.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, the 4-colour theorem is true if and only if every snark is non-planar (this is due to Tait).

Showing that a snark has a Petersen minor would be enough to show that it is non-planar.